# CASE statement bool error

Tags: sql, case

How do i change the following WHERE CASE statement to bool to make the statement work? It's giving me the error "an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected."

```
WHERE (dma.DeviceId = @DeviceID AND dma.AssociationStart = @Start AND dma.AssociationEnd = @End) AND
CASE WHEN (dma.AssociationEnd IS NOT NULL)
    THEN (SELECT m.TimeStamp FROM Measurements m WHERE m.TimeStamp BETWEEN @Start AND @End)
 ELSE 
    (SELECT m.TimeStamp FROM Measurements m WHERE m.TimeStamp BETWEEN @Start AND (SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))
END
```

Comment: Try changing the `(SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())` to just `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`. It probably won't directly solve your problem, but it will make your code nicer to read.

Comment: seeing the entire query, rather than just the `WHERE` clause would be useful for context.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a comparison. In the `WHERE` clause, you need to compare the result of that `CASE` statement to something else.

Comment: Maybe you can write down the whole SQL statement and maybe some example rows of your tables to get an idea about what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you meant to do something like:

```
SELECT m.Timestamp FROM Measurements m
WHERE dma.DeviceId = @DeviceID
  AND dma.AssociationStart = @Start
  AND dma.AssociationEnd = @End
  AND m.Timestamp BETWEEN @Start AND COALESCE(@End, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
```

*However*, the fact that `dma.AssociationEnd = @End` succeeds *already* implies that neither `dma.AssociationEnd` nor `@End` is null. So the `COALESCE` (and the whole `CASE` in the original question) is a waste of time.

(Of course, this only makes sense within a larger `SELECT` that has `dma`.)

Comment: @a1ex07: I've completely rewritten the query now, so that there's not even a `CASE`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
WHERE dma.DeviceId = @DeviceID
  AND dma.AssociationStart = @Start
  AND dma.AssociationEnd = @End
  AND EXISTS
    CASE WHEN (dma.AssociationEnd IS NOT NULL)
      THEN ( SELECT m.TimeStamp
             FROM Measurements m
             WHERE m.TimeStamp BETWEEN @Start AND @End
           )
      ELSE ( SELECT m.TimeStamp
             FROM Measurements m
             WHERE m.TimeStamp BETWEEN @Start AND SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
           )
    END
```

Comment: I adjusted the where statement a little bit and i can now select the DeviceId but when it doesn't want to compare AssociationStart and @Start.

Comment: WHERE dma.DeviceId = @DeviceID AND dma.AssociationStart > @Start AND dma.AssociationEnd = @End
    AND  (m.TimeStamp BETWEEN @Start AND (CASE 
    WHEN  dma.AssociationEnd IS NULL THEN (SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) 
    ELSE @End END))